# Is there a way to list currently exported remote objects?

Tags: java, rmi

Remote objects extending `UnicastRemoteObject` are automatically exported to the RMI system after their creation.

When the application is terminated, a thread will continue to run until all exported objects are collected by the remote garbage collector. This can be expedited by explicitely unexporting the objects before terminating the application (`UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(obj, force)`)

I know how to maintain a list of remote objects created, for example [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387203/rmi-threads-prevent-jvm-from-exiting-after-main-completes).

I would like to know if the JVM maintains a user-accessible list of objects that have been exported, and are not yet unexported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't. There is a private table of course, but none of your business.